# mismatch error when cycling through a text file in VBA

Tags: vba, type-mismatch

I have a vba script that runs through a range and adds(or subtract) numbers if they are numeric.

This script works when the files I am using are csvs or xls files.
However, when I try to run a txt file through it I get a mismatch error on the first cell for this line of code.

`If (SourceWb.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c) <> "") Then`

Does anyone have a fix for this.
The full relevant script is below.

```
For r = startR To endR
    For c = startC To endC

        If (SourceWb.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c) <> "") Then
            If IsNumeric(SourceWb.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c)) = True Then

                If plusMinus = "+" Then
                    TempWb.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c).Value2 = TempWb.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c).Value2 + SourceWb.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c).Value2 * trueUp
                Else
                    TempWb.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c).Value2 = TempWb.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c).Value2 - SourceWb.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c).Value2 * trueUp
                End If

            End If
        End If

    Next c
Next r
```

Comment: What is `SourceWB`?  What value is in `Cells(r, c)` when you get this error?

Comment: sourceWB is the file I am pulling from.
The value in the cell when I get an error is: dd->

Comment: Shouldn't you also be checking to see if `TempWb.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c).Value2` is numeric also?

Comment: I don't think so, because tempWB is simply copied and pasted from a similar file(same format just different numbers)

Comment: When the code is throwing you an error, if you press Debug, then let your mouse on the `SourceWb.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c)` text, what is shown? I would guess that is you will be seeing something like `Error ####`.

Comment: @CharlesPL I am not seeing anything when I hover my mouse over that. I am using excel 2013 if that makes a difference

Comment: In this case, could you type `? SourceWb.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c).Value` in the [immediate window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2017)? What result does it give you?

Comment: @CharlesPL its Error 2029

Answer (score 0):

A mismatch error means that VBA cannot do the operation it is trying to achieve as the type or the value is not compatible. In this case, the value of the cell is giving you a Error 2029 (#NAME?). An error is a particular value that has a particular state. Therefore, when you are trying to get the `TempWb.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c).Value2 <> ""`, VBA expects something like a string on the left side. But now it gets an error, so it cannot do the comparaison.

So, the fundamental problem is that a txt file cannot be assimilated the same way a CSV can to an Excel spreadsheet. You need to open the file and read its content line by line, put that content into a variable, then do something with this variable. A simple [Google request](https://www.google.com/search?q=Read+txt+file+vba) will get you plenty of exemples, gives and how-to. Sorry to let you hanging as this, but, you should at least try to do it by yourself.